# I'm getting error table or view doesn't exists while it exists

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle

I have implemented tables in oracle but I can't access all of them using this php:

```
$conn = oci_connect('PROJECT', 'saadbitar1998', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT ROOMNUM FROM Room');
oci_execute($stid);



//Fetch a row in an associative array
echo "<table border='1'> ";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr> ";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td> ";
    }
    echo "</tr> ";
}
echo "</table> ";
```

If i execute the same code but i select the doctors table it works but on any other table it doesn't.
PLEASE HELPP.

Comment: Make sure you create the table in the same schema which is conected from php. Else give grant to the newly created tble

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question since you didn't provide enough information. Please add your queries to the post to make others understand better your problem.